# Comment commencer une lettre de motivation ?

Tags: politesse, société, correspondance

Je voudrais envoyer une lettre à une entreprise et je voudrais savoir quelle est la meilleure façon de commencer la lettre si on ne connait pas la personne à qui on s'adresse.

> Cher Monsieur, Madame

ou

> Chère Madame, Monsieur

?

En dehors de ça, est-ce que c'est bien de utiliser le mot « cher » avant Monsieur, Dame ?

J'ai lu que ce n'est pas poli d'utiliser « cher » sans connaitre la personne à qui on s'adresse.

Comment: I have already done some research on the internet,
( http://french.about.com/library/weekly/aa111000s.htm ) But the more opinions, the better.

Comment: Pas de cher dans ce cas là. Tu peux commencer par "Messieurs". Et pour trouver des conseils et modèles: [Studyrama](http://www.studyrama-emploi.com/home_rubrique.php?id=24) ; [Digischool](http://documents.digischool.fr/Methodologie/Lettre-de-motivation/Expose-Lettre-de-motivation-performante-659.html) ; ou encore [ici](http://lettre-de-motivation.modele-cv-lettre.com/exemple-lettre-motivation.php).

Comment: Et quand on écrit à l'administration fiscale, on ne commence pas par _Cher Trésor_.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

En français, on préfère passer *Madame* avant *Monsieur*, par politesse.

Mais dans la lettre de motivation, on n'utilise pas *cher*, car nous sommes en relation de type professionnel et non émotionnel.

La meilleure formule est donc

> Madame, Monsieur,

Comment: Merci Beaucoup pour la réponse et les corrections, il y'a sept mois que je suis parti de Paris et j'avais oublié quelques choses!